# g++: "No such file or directory"

Tags: c++, cmake, g++

I am trying to install a library for lattice cryptography, which is called as NFLlib:
https://github.com/quarkslab/NFLlib

I downloaded and opened it in desktop and then follow the commands which are given in README - Install Steps:

```
$> mkdir _build
$> cd _build
$> cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$HOME/nfllib
$> make
$> make test
$> make install
```

After running `make test`, I encountered with this error:

```
The following tests FAILED:
                  5 - build_nfl_add8_60_uint32_t (Failed)
                  6 - run_nfl_add8_60_uint32_t (Not Run)
                  7 - build_nfl_sub8_60_uint32_t (Failed)
                  8 - run_nfl_sub8_60_uint32_t (Not Run)
                  9 - build_nfl_mul8_60_uint32_t (Failed)
                 10 - run_nfl_mul8_60_uint32_t (Not Run)
                 11 - build_nfl_eq8_60_uint32_t (Failed)
                 12 - run_nfl_eq8_60_uint32_t (Not Run)
                 13 - build_nfl_neq8_60_uint32_t (Failed)
                 14 - run_nfl_neq8_60_uint32_t (Not Run)
                 15 - build_nfl_stream8_60_uint32_t (Failed)
                 16 - run_nfl_stream8_60_uint32_t (Not Run)
                 17 - build_poly_p8_60_uint32_t (Failed)
                 18 - run_poly_p8_60_uint32_t (Not Run)
                 19 - build_poly_set8_60_uint32_t (Failed)
                 20 - run_poly_set8_60_uint32_t (Not Run)
                 21 - build_poly_mpz8_60_uint32_t (Failed)
                 22 - run_poly_mpz8_60_uint32_t (Not Run)
                 23 - build_poly_serialize_manually8_60_uint32_t (Failed)
                 24 - run_poly_serialize_manually8_60_uint32_t (Not Run)
                 29 - build_nfl_add128_14_uint16_t (Failed)
                 30 - run_nfl_add128_14_uint16_t (Not Run)
                 31 - build_nfl_sub128_14_uint16_t (Failed)
                 32 - run_nfl_sub128_14_uint16_t (Not Run)
                 33 - build_nfl_mul128_14_uint16_t (Failed)
                 34 - run_nfl_mul128_14_uint16_t (Not Run)
                 35 - build_nfl_eq128_14_uint16_t (Failed)
                 36 - run_nfl_eq128_14_uint16_t (Not Run)
                 37 - build_nfl_neq128_14_uint16_t (Failed)
                 38 - run_nfl_neq128_14_uint16_t (Not Run)
                 39 - build_nfl_stream128_14_uint16_t (Failed)
                 40 - run_nfl_stream128_14_uint16_t (Not Run)
                 41 - build_poly_p128_14_uint16_t (Failed)
                 42 - run_poly_p128_14_uint16_t (Not Run)
                 43 - build_poly_set128_14_uint16_t (Failed)
                 44 - run_poly_set128_14_uint16_t (Not Run)
                 45 - build_poly_mpz128_14_uint16_t (Failed)
                 46 - run_poly_mpz128_14_uint16_t (Not Run)
                 47 - build_poly_serialize_manually128_14_uint16_t (Failed)
                 48 - run_poly_serialize_manually128_14_uint16_t (Not Run)
                 53 - build_nfl_add1024_60_uint32_t (Failed)
                 54 - run_nfl_add1024_60_uint32_t (Not Run)
                 55 - build_nfl_sub1024_60_uint32_t (Failed)
                 56 - run_nfl_sub1024_60_uint32_t (Not Run)
                 57 - build_nfl_mul1024_60_uint32_t (Failed)
                 58 - run_nfl_mul1024_60_uint32_t (Not Run)
                 59 - build_nfl_eq1024_60_uint32_t (Failed)
                 60 - run_nfl_eq1024_60_uint32_t (Not Run)
                 61 - build_nfl_neq1024_60_uint32_t (Failed)
                 62 - run_nfl_neq1024_60_uint32_t (Not Run)
                 63 - build_nfl_stream1024_60_uint32_t (Failed)
                 64 - run_nfl_stream1024_60_uint32_t (Not Run)
                 65 - build_poly_p1024_60_uint32_t (Failed)
                 66 - run_poly_p1024_60_uint32_t (Not Run)
                 67 - build_poly_set1024_60_uint32_t (Failed)
                 68 - run_poly_set1024_60_uint32_t (Not Run)
                 69 - build_poly_mpz1024_60_uint32_t (Failed)
                 70 - run_poly_mpz1024_60_uint32_t (Not Run)
                 71 - build_poly_serialize_manually1024_60_uint32_t (Failed)
                 72 - run_poly_serialize_manually1024_60_uint32_t (Not Run)
                 77 - build_nfl_add8192_124_uint64_t (Failed)
                 78 - run_nfl_add8192_124_uint64_t (Not Run)
                 79 - build_nfl_sub8192_124_uint64_t (Failed)
                 80 - run_nfl_sub8192_124_uint64_t (Not Run)
                 81 - build_nfl_mul8192_124_uint64_t (Failed)
                 82 - run_nfl_mul8192_124_uint64_t (Not Run)
                 83 - build_nfl_eq8192_124_uint64_t (Failed)
                 84 - run_nfl_eq8192_124_uint64_t (Not Run)
                 85 - build_nfl_neq8192_124_uint64_t (Failed)
                 86 - run_nfl_neq8192_124_uint64_t (Not Run)
                 87 - build_nfl_stream8192_124_uint64_t (Failed)
                 88 - run_nfl_stream8192_124_uint64_t (Not Run)
                 89 - build_poly_p8192_124_uint64_t (Failed)
                 90 - run_poly_p8192_124_uint64_t (Not Run)
                 91 - build_poly_set8192_124_uint64_t (Failed)
                 92 - run_poly_set8192_124_uint64_t (Not Run)
                 93 - build_poly_mpz8192_124_uint64_t (Failed)
                 94 - run_poly_mpz8192_124_uint64_t (Not Run)
                 95 - build_poly_serialize_manually8192_124_uint64_t (Failed)
                 96 - run_poly_serialize_manually8192_124_uint64_t (Not Run)
                101 - build_nfl_add1048576_124_uint64_t (Failed)
                102 - run_nfl_add1048576_124_uint64_t (Not Run)
                103 - build_nfl_sub1048576_124_uint64_t (Failed)
                104 - run_nfl_sub1048576_124_uint64_t (Not Run)
                105 - build_nfl_mul1048576_124_uint64_t (Failed)
                106 - run_nfl_mul1048576_124_uint64_t (Not Run)
                107 - build_nfl_eq1048576_124_uint64_t (Failed)
                108 - run_nfl_eq1048576_124_uint64_t (Not Run)
                109 - build_nfl_neq1048576_124_uint64_t (Failed)
                110 - run_nfl_neq1048576_124_uint64_t (Not Run)
                111 - build_nfl_stream1048576_124_uint64_t (Failed)
                112 - run_nfl_stream1048576_124_uint64_t (Not Run)
                113 - build_poly_p1048576_124_uint64_t (Failed)
                114 - run_poly_p1048576_124_uint64_t (Not Run)
                115 - build_poly_set1048576_124_uint64_t (Failed)
                116 - run_poly_set1048576_124_uint64_t (Not Run)
                117 - build_poly_mpz1048576_124_uint64_t (Failed)
                118 - run_poly_mpz1048576_124_uint64_t (Not Run)
                119 - build_poly_serialize_manually1048576_124_uint64_t (Failed)
                120 - run_poly_serialize_manually1048576_124_uint64_t (Not Run)
Errors while running CTest
make: *** [test] Error 8
```

I think these tests are failed, since I allocated insufficient memory for virtual machine. Thus, I ignored them and continue.

Next, I finished the installation with `make install` command and I entered below to compile the demo:

```
g++ -Ilib -lnfllib_static.a -std=c++11 nfllib_demo_main_op.cpp
```

This time the following error is shown:

```
In file included from nfllib_demo_main_op.cpp:1:0:
nfllib_demo_main.hpp:4:19: fatal error: nfl.hpp: No such file or directory
 #include "nfl.hpp"
```

I could not understand the reason for this error, since the header locates in the right folder as you can see from the above link. Maybe something is wrong with the command that I typed to compile the demo. Please excuse my ignorance about basic C++-commands. How can I complete installation of the library and compile the demo?

Edit (mindoo's advice):

Command:

```
g++ -Ilib -lnfllib_static.a -std=c++11 nfllib_demo_main_op.cpp nfl.hpp
```

Result:

```
In file included from nfl.hpp:17:0,
                 from nfllib_demo_main.hpp:4,
                 from nfllib_demo_main_op.cpp:1:
nfl/poly.hpp:23:25: fatal error: nfl/debug.hpp: No such file or directory
 #include "nfl/debug.hpp"
                         ^
compilation terminated.
In file included from nfl.hpp:17:0:
nfl/poly.hpp:23:25: fatal error: nfl/debug.hpp: No such file or directory
 #include "nfl/debug.hpp"
                         ^
compilation terminated.
```

Comment: Probably there is a command to build the tests.

Comment: `I could not understand the reason for this error, since the header locates in the right folder` - Headers are located in the folder `include`, but you include directory `lib` (by option `-Ilib`).

Answer (score -1):

I'm not really good with libraries and their installation, but I do usually compile using the command line and g++.
Could you possibly try to do :

```
g++ -Ilib -lnfllib_static.a -std=c++11 nfllib_demo_main_op.cpp nfl.hpp
```

Tell me if that worked